# Facebook Like button became red : you are being spammy

Tags: hyperlink, facebook-like, spam, blocked

I have a few like buttons on my page and I was running some tests (well.. a lot of tests) with them. Now it's displaying well but when I click on them, them becomes red, says "error" and a popup appears saying :

**The content you're trying to share includes a link that's been blocked for being spammy or unsafe:Body of an error/warning message. Title is: You can't post this because it has a blocked link.For more information, visit the Help Center. If you think you're seeing this by mistake, please let us know.**

I tried to change the data-href by other URLs but the problem is the same. Is it linked to my facebook account ? My IP ? My application ?

Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a customer service question.

Answer (score 0):

I used this one to fix mine. This one doesn't have a bug i think, coz it doesn't show the error like the small like button does.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/